# cors error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, postman

When I send a *HTTP Get* request to [this web uri](https://www.aponet.de/apotheke/apothekensuche?tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Baction%5D=result&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bcontroller%5D=Search&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Bplzort%5D=rothenburg&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Bstreet%5D=&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Bradius%5D=10&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Blat%5D=&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Blng%5D=&type=1981) via [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), the [response is returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtUan.png), but when I send a request like below, I get a cors error. ?

```
const getData = async () => {
const url = " https://www.aponet.de/apotheke/apothekensuche?tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Baction%5D=result&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bcontroller%5D=Search&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Bplzort%5D=rothenburg&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Bstreet%5D=&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Bradius%5D=10&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Blat%5D=&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Blng%5D=&type=1981 "
         
axios.get(url)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

Comment: this is because, the server hasn't enabled CORS. "Postman is not a browser, so is not limited by CORS policy"

Comment: so what should i do to get cors error?

Comment: That has to be done by the team at "https://www.aponet.de". They get to set the CORS policy. You get to access resource via the browser, if the policy allow you to do so.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, postman offers "Code Snippet" functions for developers to obtain the API fetch code directly after testing. It locates on the right of the window with icon "</>".

Here is the code provided by postman.

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://www.aponet.de/apotheke/apothekensuche?tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Baction%5D=result&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bcontroller%5D=Search&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Bplzort%5D=rothenburg&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Bstreet%5D=&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Bradius%5D=10&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Blat%5D=&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Blng%5D=&type=1981", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

For axios

```
var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://www.aponet.de/apotheke/apothekensuche?tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Baction%5D=result&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bcontroller%5D=Search&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Bplzort%5D=rothenburg&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Bstreet%5D=&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Bradius%5D=10&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Blat%5D=&tx_aponetpharmacy_search%5Bsearch%5D%5Blng%5D=&type=1981',
  headers: { }
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Not an answer. It still gives "CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error.

Comment: Not an answer. i keep getting the error.

Comment: May I ask that where do you call this fetch function? Through a browser? Or from your website which the domain is not "www.aponet.de" ?

Comment: I'm trying with the axios package in the react project.

Comment: Since I tried the code above in react-native app project and it works. And I remember that you cannot simply call API from other domain website. It will blocked by CORS policy.